# Vector : References to generic type Vector<E> should be parameterized

Tags: jsp, generics, vector

I have this problem(yellow line) in my jsp file which often caused my eclipse program keep no responding. Although my program can run, but how can i get a rid of this following line of code.

[image]

```
Vector vFieldName       = (Vector) session.getAttribute("table_vFieldName_"+TABLE_TYPE);
Vector vTable           = session.getAttribute("table_vTable_"+TABLE_TYPE) == null ? new Vector(): (Vector) session.getAttribute("table_vTable_"+TABLE_TYPE);   

for (int k=0;k<vTable.size();k++)
{
   intSeqNo=vTable.size();
   Vector vRow  = (Vector) vTable.elementAt(k);       
}
```

Comment: What data type is contained inside Vector?

Comment: the vector value is like =  [1,apple,13.50,red], [2,orange,6.50,orange],[3,grape,3.50,purple]

Comment: Start by getting rid of Vector. Use List and ArrayList instead. And never use raw types. Use List<Something> and not just List. If a given list contains numbers, fruits and colors, then you have a serious design problem. Using Java code in JSPs is also a big design problem. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL. You're programming as if we were stuck in 1999, with Java 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so these warnings would hang your IDE, these are harmless. And also it is always a best practice to specify the type for generics like `Vectar<Object>` or `Vectar<String>` or `List<String>` or `ArrayList<String>` etc and not use raw types.

Please read from updated sources and books. It is the era of Java-8 and not Java-1! [image]

Anyways if still you want to get rid of these warnings then:

1. Right click on your project
2. Go to Properties
3. Search for "JSP"
4. Select JSP syntax and scroll down to Java as shown:

   [image: Project properties/Preferences for JSP]
5. Click on Error/Warnings as shown
6. Scroll down to Generic types and select "Ignore" for `Usage of raw types` as shown:

   [image: Generic types settings for the project]
7. Apply, rebuild project and you are done.

Also as a side suggestion, it is better to use `ArrayList` or other `List`s instead of `Vectar`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) for why not to use Vectar.

Also avoid using Java code as much as possible in JSPs though sometimes it might be necessary but in most case we can avoid. Use [el](/questions/tagged/el) or [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the clear explanation !!